# PhpStorm: Run PHP server doesn't work: could not find driver

Tags: php, phpstorm, interpreter, built-in-web-server

I am using PhpStorm for a year and now I want to run my PHP server using the PHP Run menu:

[image: PhpStorm run server button]

I run the server pushing the green arrow button. Then the console show:

```
/home/john/.cache/JetBrains/PhpStorm2020.1/plugins/idea-php-latest-plugin/php-v7.3.1/php.sh -S localhost:8080 -t /home/john/my-nice-project/backend/web
```

Then I go to `localhost:8080` in my browser and I see this error:

[image]

I execute php -v in my terminal and I can see this:

```
PHP 7.2.34-18+0~20210223.60+debian10~1.gbpb21322 (cli) (built: Feb 23 2021 16:47:51) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.34-18+0~20210223.60+debian10~1.gbpb21322, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

So maybe the problem is the version of the PHP interpreter: I have 7.2.34 and PhpStorm has php-v7.3.1 configure.

Is there any way to configure the version?

But if I execute this command, it works fine:

```
php yii serve --docroot="backend/web/"
```

Comment: Check PDO Extension is installed or not

Comment: If PDO extension is not installed, check this https://askubuntu.com/a/824505

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your php.ini file:
`extension=pdo.so`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php

Comment: On Ubuntu, easy to do `apt install php7.0-mysql` rather then building extension from source